# Want to turn output into an array nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, onesignal

I have a function returning an array that looks like this:

```
.then(Cause.findOne(causeId).populate('admins').exec(function (err, cause) {

var ids = cause.admins.map(function(admin) {
  return admin.id;
})
   var join_ids = "'" + ids.join("','");
```

The output of console.log(join_ids);

```
'26c14292-a181-48bd-8344-73fa9caf65e7','64405c09-61d2-43ed-8b15-a99f92dff6e9','bdc034df-82f5-4cd8-a310-a3c3e2fe3106'
```

I am trying to pass the first value of the array into another function as a userId filter:

```
    let message = {
  app_id: `${app_id}`,
  contents: {"en": "Yeah Buddy," + Cause.name + "Rolling Like a Big Shot!"},
  filters: [{'field': 'tag', 'key': 'userId', 'relation': '=', 'value': `${join_ids}`}]
```

And the output of console.log(message);

```
    { app_id: '*****************',
  contents: { en: 'Yeah Buddy,undefinedRolling Like a Big Shot!' },
  filters: 
   [ { field: 'tag',
       key: 'userId',
       relation: '=',
       value: '\'26c14292-a181-48bd-8344-73fa9caf65e7\',\'64405c09-61d2-43ed-8b15-a99f92dff6e9\',\'bdc034df-82f5-4cd8-a310-a3c3e2fe3106' } ],
  ios_badgeType: 'Increase',
  ios_badgeCount: 1 }
```

If I put the console.log(join_ids[0]);

```
2
```

console.log(message);

```
        { app_id: '*****************',
  contents: { en: 'Yeah Buddy,undefinedRolling Like a Big Shot!' },
  filters: 
   [ { field: 'tag',
       key: 'userId',
       relation: '=',
       value: 2} ],
  ios_badgeType: 'Increase',
  ios_badgeCount: 1 }
```

My question is how do I turn the output of join_ids to become an array where indices are 0,1,2,3.

I.E.

```
join_ids[0] = '26c14292-a181-48bd-8344-73fa9caf65e7', join_ids[1] = '64405c09-61d2-43ed-8b15-a99f92dff6e9'
```

Thanks!

Comment: To serialize an array to a string, you can just use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). To convert it back to an array, use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your 2nd code snippet, it looks like its already an array.  to confirm this you can try to console.log the following:

```
console.log(join_ids.length) // if this returns zero-based length then its an array

console.log(typeof(join_ids)) // get the TYPE of the variable 

console.log(join_ids[0])  // see if you can address the FIRST value individually


// for each loop over the array and console out EACH item in the array
for (var i = 0; i < join_ids.lenght; i++) {
    console.log(join_ids[i]);
}
```

if you find that its a string, I would remove the apostrophes

```
yourstring = yourstring.replace(/'/g, "")  // replaces all apostrophes
```

and the space after the commas, if present, then just wrap the value in double quotes and do

```
join_ids = join_ids.split(',');  // makes the comma separated values an array
```

[Fiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/7uowjkfe/).

Comment: Sorry, I dont think my question was clear. The output is in array format, I just want the first value to be join_ids[0] = '26c14292-a181-48bd-8344-73fa9caf65e7', join_ids[1] = '64405c09-61d2-43ed-8b15-a99f92dff6e9'

Comment: just added a part that should help... it looks like its a STRING ... so use regular expression to remove all apostrophes, and you're left with just a comma separated string of values... then do join_ids.split(',') ... this will make join_ids[0] be the first full value (the item BEFORE the first comma, or  the array value at position 0).  Does that help?

Comment: also see the JS fiddle link I just added where I illustrate cleaning the string up, converting to an array and then grabbing just one of the array items.

Comment: Thanks for your split function that helped split it up. Do you have any idea how I could remove the escape functions or get around them? I'm trying to just send:


`'value': '<id value>'`

Comment: escape characters*

Comment: not sure I understand your reference to 'escape characters'... can you elaborate or show me an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130747/discussion-between-tamak-and-user2019182).